# Android game - Widgets or hard-coded widgets?

Tags: android, widget, surfaceview

I've been following some tutorials on getting off the ground.  I wanted to put some kind of widgets into the game, but the problem is surface view won't let you use widgets like buttons.  I saw that a framelayout view will work, but I wonder if I should go through the trouble of trying this or make my own widget that behaves like a button.  Just has a touchable hitbox that checks the press and acts accordingly.

What would be the best way I wonder...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can definitively say which way is BEST. As far as coding complexity goes, my first suggestion below is probably easier. You will likely have more control over how the widgets work in the context of your game if you use the second suggestion.

Technically you can use buttons with a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), and I believe this has to be done with a separate Layout that is layered below (I think) the SurfaceView (I'm not as familiar with this method). To use this type of approach, you would need to store the bounding rectangles of your widgets (I have done this using `Rect`), then when you override your `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method you will use `Rect(use your bounding rectangles here).contains(event.getX(), event.getY());` to get determine if the location of the actual TouchEvent corresponds with the location of your widget. If that returns true, set a flag on your widget so when your background Thread runs, it will see the flag and perform some function (ex. open an inventory screen).

From what I have read, it's perfectly viable to just create a Bitmap for your widget and draw that to your SurfaceView. You will still have to calculate where touch events occur in relation to where your bitmap widget is. If you use this bitmap approach, you should probably keep in mind that if you are making a checkbox, for example, you will need multiple versions of the bitmap so it looks like it has been checked / unchecked when the user touches it.

Here are some resources I have found extremely helpful in learning Android game development:

This link is for a very well written set of tutorials that teaches you how to make a legit 2D game:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/android-game-development-tutorials.html

This link has a very good explanation of how the Android system interprets and processes TouchEvents across multiple layers of UI layouts:
http://balpha.de/2013/07/android-development-what-i-wish-i-had-known-earlier/

Good overview of game design concepts:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/21205/62663

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Coding the touch box for a button isn't too hard...  Just felt kind of sloppy.  But I suppose a normal button would be about the same amount of code anyway.

I checked out the links.  The first one had some nice tips/steps.  Unrelated, but I liked how that one regulated frame rate a little bit better, so I implemented that as well

I will make something work.  I always do. :)  Thanks.